# orapki command line utility for creating wallet is not working

Tags: java, oracle12c

orapki utility for managing Public Key Infrustrure (PKI) like wallet is not working.
 It is showing following error in Linux shell.

> bash: orapki: command not found...

In the system, `Oracle 12c` is installed, `ORACLE_HOME` is set and oraclepki jar is also present in `Oracle_home/jlib` dir. 
Anyone, please help me understand the cause and its solution.

Comment: Did you configure JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score -1):

`orapki` is under `MIDDLEWARE_HOME/oracle_common/bin`

Try invoking orapki from this path, or add to `PATH` env var.